# How to enforce explicit return type of object's methods in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to enforce do explicit declare a return type of all functions and methods in the code.

So I set `'@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'error'`.
But it's **not always** works:

This is okay, `eslint` throws an error:

```
const obj = {
  fn() {   // <---- no return type, so "Missing return type on function" error
    return 2;
  }
};
```

This is NOT okay, `eslint` see NO problems here:

```
const obj: Record<string, any> = { // <---- But if I declare a type of an object...
  fn() {   // <---- ...this is throws no error anymore!
    return 2;
  }
};
```

How can I make sure that there is no methods without explicit return type definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule you are using has an option called [`allowTypedFunctionExpressions`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md#allowtypedfunctionexpressions) that can be explicitly set to `false` to get what you want:

```js
...
"rules": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error", { "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": false }],
    ...
},
...
```